# How can move InnoDB table from one pc to another pc?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've a table 'admin' and I want to move that with all data from one location to another. If I use MyISAM engine then I get 3 files 'admin.frm','admin.MYD' and 'admin.MYI' for 'admin' table in data folder, and I can copy and paste those files to another location and can run the table. but if I use InnoDB engine then I get only 'admin.frm' in data folder and when copy that file to another location then the table can't be run.

Anybody please tell me how can I move InnoDB table from one location to another ?

-Thanks.

***Edit:*** (I need to transfer data and structure too(as entire table).I want it simple copy paste like MyISAM table files. is it possible ? and how ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to transfer data it may be simpler to use the built in tools, as so...

Use mysqldump to get your table, a very simple example:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE admin > admin.sql
```

And then on the other computer:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < admin.sql
```

Comment: I need to transfer data and structure too(as entire tables).I want it simple copy paste like MyISAM table files. how is it possible ?

Comment: mysqldump by default should include the create info, which will have a CREATE TABLE statement. You should not be copying MyISAM files unless you have identical my.cnf on both machines and are on the same major version.

Comment: is 'mysqldump' the only solution in this case ? is there any other solution else ?

Comment: mysqldump is the typical canonical solution. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another has plenty of other possible solutions, but none are as trivial or typically used.

Comment: I see, so would you please explain the solution in a bit details ? would I write "mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE admin > admin.sql" on mysql shell on the pc where my database is currently in ? then what would happen ? would you please tell me step by step ?

Comment: You would issue both commands on the command line / shell. Transfer the resulting file, and issue the command beginning with "mysql" on the target.

Comment: I wrote "mysqldump -u -p test t > t.sql;" in mysql command promt and got error. (here 't' is a table,database is 'test'and I don't have database username or password.) whats wrong did I do ?

Comment: These commands are not issued on the mysql command line, they are issued on the system command line.

Comment: oh, I'm getting messed up with it. I would have to learn mysqldump well. but thanks for your solution, now I know by using mysqldump I can move innodb tables.

Comment: now I wrote "mysqldump -u -p test t > t.sql" on mysql shell and got a text file named 't'. so now would I have to copy this file and paste to another pc on same location and then write "mysql -u -p test t > t.sql" on that pc mysql shell ?

Comment: Close, "mysql -u MYSQLUSERNAME -p test < t.sql"

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to dump all the data to a file which you can then run on the other machine?

Answer (score 0):

Move Innodb using tablespace methods in 5.6 version:

1)  Create empty table on destination server/database same as on source server.

2)  Discard tablespace on destination server.

```
Alter Table table_name discard tablespace.
```

3)  Copy .frm and .ibd to destination server after executing "flush tables with read lock" on source server.

4)  Import tablespace on destination server :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```